# How to automate a command with PHP in web app

Tags: php, command

I have a directory that when accessed through the terminal, I run the command 'make' then 'make install' which subsequently builds a dictionary file. I want to automate this process, which will kick off when the user selects a button on the interface.

Using PHP in my web app I want to navigate to the directory which I have done so here:

```
chdir('../DictionaryFolder');
```

Then, I thought this PHP command would run the make and make install:

```
exec(make);
exec(make install);
```

But this does nothing.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the command like the following,

```
<?php 
     $output = shell_exec('make;make install;');
     echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Shell exec will do the trick by calling $output via pre tag.

Comment: The output displayed (for some reason, only the first 4 lines) is as expected, but the dictionary file which is normally built when the command is run from the terminal, does not appear

Comment: Sorry, I realised the permissions on the folder I was trying to access were read only, after changing to read & write it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Exec() try to execute PHP like eval() in JS, shel_exec execute commande like you with CLI